# Replace text wrapped in a button tag w with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Trying to replace some text wrapped in a button tag, but this jquery doesn't seem to work for me. Any suggestions?

```
<div id="memorabilia">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="load">More Memorabilia</button>
</div>
```

```js
$('#load').text(function() {
  $(this).text('MÉG TÖBB MEMORABILIA');
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nqfz5340/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import jQuery first. Place your code inside a method like .ready or .click that will trigger the event.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#load').text(function() {
        jQuery(this).text('MÉG TÖBB MEMORABILIA');
    })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="memorabilia">
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="load">More Memorabilia</button>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

You can ommit the second line. So the final code will be

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#load').text('MÉG TÖBB MEMORABILIA');
});
```

Comment: There's no need for the function being passed to `text()`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thank you.